# python get data json value max

Tags: python, json

How can I extract the T3 Period, Year and maximum value?

*file.json*

```
[
{"Fecha":"2022-08-01T00:00:00.000+02:00", "T3_TipoDato":"Avance", "T3_Periodo":"M08", "Anyo":2022, "value":10.4},
{"Fecha":"2022-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00", "T3_TipoDato":"Definitivo", "T3_Periodo":"M07", "Anyo":2022, "value":10.8},
{"Fecha":"2022-06-01T00:00:00.000+02:00", "T3_TipoDato":"Definitivo", "T3_Periodo":"M06", "Anyo":2022, "value":10.2}
]
```

My code:

```
import json

with open("file.json") as f: 
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

print (distros_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

that is my proposition.

1. Load data from a file to a list.
2. Loop thru every dict in a list to edit it.
   (At my example I, deleted two keys from every dict in list.)

```
   import json
   
   distros_dict = []
   
   with open(f'file.json', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
       distros_dict.extend(json.load(f))
   
   for item in distros_dict:
     item.pop('Fecha')
     item.pop('T3_TipoDato')

   distros_dict = sorted(distros_dict, key = lambda i: i['value'], reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: and valur max, how can show.... example:
{'T3_Periodo': 'M07', 'Anyo': 2022, 'Valor': 10.8}

Comment: hi, sorry I miss understood. Now I added one (last line) to my code. That way I sort list by key 'value', reverse it and grab first item. I hope that is what you wanted

Comment: Of course using and transforming that code you can delete any unnecesary keys from your data, and use the last line to sort them  using certain keys.

Comment: how could it be:

T3_Periodo = M07
Anyo = 2022
value = 10.8

Comment: Sir, please articulate your full thoughts, to be understood better. You asked to: 
load data, then pick dictionary (element of that list) with highest 'value' and grab only T3_periodo, anyo and value of that element. Should be marked as done. If you are looking for specific displaying format, or anything other you should include that within your question not in the comment, otherway answers will never meet expectiations. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from json import load

with open("file.json") as f:
    dictionary_max = max(load(f), key=lambda x: x["value"])

result = {
    "T3_Periodo": dictionary_max["T3_Periodo"],
    "Anyo": dictionary_max["Anyo"],
    "value": dictionary_max["value"],
}

print(result)
```

output:

```
{'T3_Periodo': 'M07', 'Anyo': 2022, 'value': 10.8}
```